# GraphQL for Time Series

Tags: time-series, analytics, graphql

Based on this talk: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=srfaKA2wJ0s

I would like to implement an analytics/time series query in GraphQL like

```
query {
   sales(date: { start: ‘2017-01-01’, end: ‘2018-01-01’ }) {
       revenue(stat: mean)
       daily: interval(by: day) {
          date
          revenue
       }
   }
}
```

revenue(stat: mean) is an aggregation based on one statistic (mean in this case)
daily is a list of data points by hour/day/month

How to implement this using mongodb, or postgresql/mysql databases in a performant way?

Answer (score 3):

Having given this a bit more thought...

I'd have `sales(date: { start: ‘2017-01-01’, end: ‘2018-01-01’ })` resolve to an object that looks like this:

```
{
   __type: 'SalesDateSelection',
   start: ‘2017-01-01’,
   end: '2018-01-01',
}
```

This is free because it's just a dumb object that holds the arguments it was created with, no expensive data access going on here.

Each of the child fields (`revenue(stat: mean)` and `interval(by: day)`) can then be resolved using a combination of their arguments and the data on this parent object. Which would presumably be 2 database queries?

Comment: what about interval part that return a list of data points? the resolver should be in `interval` on in each child field of `interval`?

Comment: i'd expect that expensive data loading to be on `interval` and it to return an array of `{ date, revenue }` objects.

Comment: my current implementation makes interval return an array of objects with date and by arg. and each child field have a resolver for each data point, I'll move to materialized views to make it faster, tks for the help